# MySQL - How To Optimize thie Query

Tags: mysql

I have a complex query, that while relatively fast for a distance-based ranking query (~0.6 seconds) is not fast enough. The query needs to be run for each zip code in the US which results in a total running time of around 6 hours and 40 minutes. Is there anyway that this can be optimized?

```
SELECT mt.*,
       da.dealPrice,
       da.dealSavings,
       da.dealOriginalPrice,
       da.dealDiscountPercent FROM
  ( SELECT businessType,title,rank,createDate,address1,city,STATE,ZIP,deal_ID,dealSaving FROM
     ( SELECT IF(@businessType=businessType,@ctr:=@ctr+1,@ctr:=1) AS RowNum, @businessType:=businessType AS businessType,title,rank,createDate,address1,city,STATE,ZIP,deal_ID,dealSaving
      FROM
        ( SELECT deal_ID,title,distance,userProvider_ID,age_rank,createDate,address1,city,STATE,ZIP,dealSaving, age_rank * EXP(-POWER(GREATEST(distance-distance_scale,0),2)/((-2*POWER(distance_scale,2))/(2*LOG(distance_decay)))) AS rank, age,businessType
         FROM
           (SELECT sd.deal_ID,sd.dealURL,TRIM(sd.dealSaving) AS dealSaving,TRIM(sd.title) AS title,sd.userProvider_ID,p.radius,distance_scale,distance_decay,d.createDate, p.distance_unit*DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))*COS(RADIANS(sd.storeLat))*COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - sd.storeLon))+SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))*SIN(RADIANS(sd.storeLat)))) AS distance, EXP(-POWER(GREATEST(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),d.createDate)-SCALE,0),2)/((-2*POWER(SCALE,2))/(2*LOG(decay)))) AS age_rank,sd.businessType,sd.store_ID, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),d.createDate) AS age,sd.address1,sd.city,sd.STATE,sd.ZIP
            FROM search_deals sd
            LEFT JOIN deals d ON sd.deal_ID = d.dealID
            JOIN
              ( SELECT 40.6812509 AS latpoint,-73.9809685 AS longpoint,50.0 AS radius,69.0 AS distance_unit,5 AS SCALE,0.5 AS decay, 1 AS distance_scale, 0.001 AS distance_decay ) AS p ON 1=1
            WHERE sd.storeLat BETWEEN p.latpoint - (p.radius / p.distance_unit) AND p.latpoint + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
              AND sd.storeLon BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)))) AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
              AND d.createDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -90 DAY)
              AND sd.flag = 0
              AND sd.STATE = 'NY'
              AND sd.userProvider_ID > 0
              AND sd.businessType IN (1,2,3)
            GROUP BY store_ID ) AS d
         WHERE distance <= radius
         ORDER BY rank DESC ) main
      JOIN
        (SELECT @ctr:=1) AS a
      ORDER BY businessType, rank DESC) AS b
   WHERE RowNum <= 5) mt
LEFT JOIN deals_addon da ON mt.deal_ID = da.deal_ID;
```

Running explain for the query results in the following:

```
+------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type        | possible_keys                                                               | key        | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra                                    |
+------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | <derived2> | ALL         | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      | 14136 |                                          |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | da         | ref         | deal_ID                                                                     | deal_ID    | 9       | mt.deal_ID                |     1 | Using where                              |
|    2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | ALL         | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      | 14136 | Using where                              |
|    3 | DERIVED     | <derived7> | system      | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      |     1 | Using filesort                           |
|    3 | DERIVED     | <derived5> | ALL         | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      | 14136 | Using where                              |
|    7 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL        | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      |  NULL | No tables used                           |
|    5 | DERIVED     | <derived6> | system      | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      |     1 | Using temporary; Using filesort          |
|    5 | DERIVED     | sd         | index_merge | search_lat_long,search_deal_ID,flag,state,userProvider_ID,drupal_1,drupal_2 | state,flag | 5,1     | NULL                      | 18848 | Using intersect(state,flag); Using where |
|    5 | DERIVED     | d          | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,idx_createDate,createDate                                           | PRIMARY    | 8       | tb2099_9pprod.sd.deal_ID  |     1 | Using where                              |
|    6 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL        | NULL                                                                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                      |  NULL | No tables used                           |
+------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why would you run the query separately on each zip code?  Write one query to process all zip codes at the same time.

Comment: I'm unsure how to join it with the zip code table, as I would need to use the coordinates from that table to complete the query required here.

Comment: Can you edit your question (or supply an SQL Fiddle) with your actual table design, and perhaps a few rows of sample data? That way, it would be easier for other users to try and optimize this query because they could test a new one against your original results and make sure it still returns the same.