# Put a specific row first and then order by a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

EDIT: The goal is to order the output so that the first result is the row with store_id = 5 and the maximum rank of all items with store_id = 5. Then the rest of the deals are ranked according to their rank in descending order, regardless of their store_id. For the actual query, a union would be too expensive.

An example of data would be:

```
+----+----------+------+
| id | store_id | rank |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 |   1      |  10  |
+----+----------+------+
|  2 |   5      |   9  |
+----+----------+------+
|  3 |   4      |   8  |
+----+----------+------+
|  4 |   3      |   7  |
+----+----------+------+
|  5 |   3      |   6  |
+----+----------+------+
|  6 |   1      |   5  |
+----+----------+------+
```

The final query being run would be:

```
SELECT id,store_ID,IF(@id=id,rank=rank*9999999,rank) AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id,rank,store_id
        FROM items
    ) b
    JOIN (@id:=(SELECT id FROM b WHERE store_id = 5 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1)) AS s
)
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

And the desired outcome would be:

```
+----+----------+------+
| id | store_id | rank |
+----+----------+------+
|  2 |   5      |   9  |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 |   1      |  10  |
+----+----------+------+
|  3 |   4      |   8  |
+----+----------+------+
|  4 |   3      |   7  |
+----+----------+------+
|  5 |   3      |   6  |
+----+----------+------+
|  6 |   1      |   5  |
+----+----------+------+
```

Here (@id:=(SELECT id FROM b WHERE store_id = 5 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1)) is being used to select the top scoring item with store_id = 5. This item is meant to appear first in the list, hence why it is reranked by multiplying it by a very large number. All other ranks remain untouched and are ranked according to their score in descending order.

The problem is that the select statement in the join is trying to join a selection from a subquery called b. However, table b does not actually exist in the database, so MySQL is saying that table b does not exist. How can I reference the subquery? The actual subquery is incredibly complex, so I haven't included it here, but if interested you can see a version of it here: [MySQL - How To Optimize thie Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621668/mysql-how-to-optimize-thie-query?noredirect=1#comment43663825_27621668). The query in this question is just to keep the problem simple.

Comment: Can you make an example with some data, I really don't get what do you want to obtain

Comment: can you describe with words with example what you're trying to accomplish. So far I cant tell what you want to do.

Comment: You can add another `non-existing` column that represent computed-rank  and if store_id is 5 than it gets the value of 2 otherwise 1. Then all you need to do is to change for `ORDER BY computedRank, rank DESC`

Comment: Two questions that may be your problem. 1) Why do you have `FROM( FROM(`? Are you are missing the `ON` clause of your join?

Answer (score 11):

You can adjust your order by clause to put a specific row first. Let's say you wanted store_id 5 to be first, you can do this:

```
ORDER BY store_id = 5 DESC, rank DESC;
```

Which will put the row with store_id 5 on top. In this example, you want the row that has the highest rank for store_id 5, so I wrote the following subquery:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable
WHERE store_id = 5
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And I put that in the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY id = 
      (SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE store_id = 5 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1) DESC, 
   rank DESC;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0adb87/6).

**EDIT**

If you put a subquery in your `FROM` clause, you won't be able to reference its alias in the subquery of the `ORDER BY` clause. However, in a very unreadable fashion, you can put the same subquery there to accomplish it, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) b
ORDER BY id = 
   (SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) b WHERE store_id = 5 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1) DESC, 
   rank DESC;
```

Another [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0adb87/9).

Comment: I like this solution, but the problem is that I need to select from the subquery generated table b. As b does not exist in my database I get the following error message: Table 'b' doesn't exist

Comment: This is due to this post being an overly simplified version of the query which actually calculates ranks through a series of decay and distance functions. Due to this it has to base the order by select based on this subquery, b.

Comment: Doesn't my query order based on the results of the subquery? I know I gave a solution different from the query you had, but it does answer the question doesn't it?

Comment: It does result in the desired output. The problem I'm having is trying to get it to work on the subquery, which is a requirement for the actual application. The sample query in the SQL Fiddle would be SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) b
ORDER BY id = (SELECT id FROM b WHERE store_id = 5 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1) DESC, rank DESC;

Comment: @user2694306 I guess I just don't understand why you need that subquery, it doesn't do anything special. Also, it shouldn't work because you're creating two separate subqueries that don't have access to each other.

Comment: @user2694306 if you have to, you can try something like I have shown in the edit to my answer.

Comment: The new answer still requires the full subquery to execute in the (SELECT * FROM myTable) b. This contains a variation of the subquery which would show why that solution wouldn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621668/mysql-how-to-optimize-thie-query?noredirect=1#comment43663825_27621668